# Mailing using SmartGroup sends to recipients not in the Smart Group

Tags: civimail

I had a scheduled mailing set to run today at at 8am. When I look at the list of people who received the email, more were sent the email than were in the SmartGroup mailing list.

The SmartGroup had a 136 contacts, but the mailing was sent to 170 contacts.

This is in civiCRM  5.14.1. under Joomla 3.9.8. 
I have my Rebuild Smart Group Cache scheduled job set to run every time cron runs
and Update Membership Statuses scheduled job set to run Daily

Here's a video explaining this in more detail:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hCmN9N9FHr9k0V1X1FYGPFbxzZKzOnUY/view?usp=drivesdk

Note I didn't verbally mention it in the video, but at 1:05:12 you can see that the Recipients included only the single SmartGroup.

Can any shed some light on how this could happen?

I created the smart group using the Search Builder, and here are the filters:

[image]

Comment: Your video doesn't show the criteria for the smart group.  Could you add a screenshot?  In particular, is the smart group built using Search Builder?

Comment: I used Search Builder, and I've added screen shot above.

Comment: Try upgrading to Civi 5.15.0?  I worked on what I believe is a similar bug in Search Builder last month and it's likely to be fixed now.